# How can I use a provider value to useMutation and also dispatch the changes to state afterwards?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-apollo

I would like to use a Context.Provider value to handle both mutating and dispatching similar changes. I have read about React-Apollo's onComplete method, but I'm not sure which approach will cover more cases where I need to both mutate and dispatch state. Here's what I have:

```
const CartContext = React.createContext<{
  state: State
  dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>
  cartApi: any
}>({ state: initialState, dispatch: () => null, cartApi: mutateUserProductsAndUpdateCart })

function CartProvider({ children }: { children?: React.ReactNode }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<Reducer<State, AnyAction>>(reducer, initialState)

  // feel like i need to do something with the hook here to avoid invariant violation side effects
  const [updateUserProducts] = useUpdateUserProducts()
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch, cartApi: mutateUserProductsAndUpdateCart}}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  )
}
export const useCartState = () => useContext(CartContext)
```

And here's what I would *like* to do with my mutateUserProductsAndUpdateCart:

```
const mutateUserProductsAndUpdateCart = async (_mutation: any, _mutationParams: any, _dispatchObject: AnyObject) => {
  // apollo mutation
  const updateUserProductsResult = await updateUserProducts(_mutationParams)

  if (updateUserProductsResult.error) throw Error("wtf")

  // useReducer dispatch
  dispatch(_dispatchObject)

  return
}
```

and here is how I would like to access this on another component:

```
const { cartApi } = useCartState()
const addProductToCart = async () => {
  const result = await cartApi({
    mutation,
    mutationVariables,
    dispatchObject})
}
```

I feel like [this](https://medium.com/trabe/passing-callbacks-down-with-react-hooks-4723c4652aff) article is sort of the direction I should be taking, but I'm very lost on implementation here. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this directly answers your question, but have you considered just using Apollo Client?  It looks like you are trying to do two things:

1. Save items added to the cart to the server
2. Update the cart locally in the cache

It seems like you could skip creating your own context altogether and just create a hook for mutating (saving your cart items) and then update your local cache for cart items.  Something like this:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import useMutation from '@apollo/client';

export const mutation = gql`
  mutation($items: [CartItem]!) {
    saveCartItems(items: $items) {
      id
      _list_of_properties_for_cache_update_
    }
  }
`;

export const useSaveCartItems = mutationProps => {
  const [saveCartItems, result] = useMutation(
    mutation,
    mutationProps
  );

  return [
    items => {
      saveCartItems({
        update: (cache, { data }) => {
          const query = getCartQuery; // Some query to get the cart items from the cache
          const results = cache.readQuery({ query });

          // We need to add new items only; existing items will auto-merge
          // Get list of new items from results
          const data = []; // List of new items; IMPLEMENT ME!!!

          cache.writeQuery({ query, data });
        },
        variables: { items },
      });
    },
    result,
  ];
};
```

Then in your `useCartState` hook you can just query the local cache for the items using the same query you used for the `update` and return that.  By using the `update` function you can fix your local cache and anybody can access it from anywhere, just use the hook.  I know that isn't exactly what you asked for, but I hope it helps.

Apollo client documentation on handling this may be found [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#making-all-other-cache-updates).

Comment: I have thought about this approach, the issue is that there's many components that have logic depending on useCartState's state/dispatch, unless I could use some sort of memo that handles changes to the cache? I'm not all too familiar with apollo.

Comment: Whenever the cache updates the components using those cache values re-render.  So by default, whenever the cache updates it will dispatch the changes to all related components.  The TLP (top-level provider) is what stores the data, and it provides a context that is accessed whenever useQuery/useMutation is called.  So if that stored data updates the context changes, which causes components to re-render.  So you already have a context providing the latest data at all times and dispatching whenever the data changes.  Isn't that what you are trying to achieve?